# PHP & MONGO: nested find query $and $or $ne

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, count, find

I am trying to make a query where I want to retrieve items querying a field in the database.
I need to check something as follows (example):

To retrieve books where the text field contain "Soccer" or "Basketball":

I want to have the items where only in the population above:

contain '1989'

and

exclude 'Europe'

Any idea? I am doing a counting for now but it does not work:

```
    //search words
    foreach ($cardSearch as $value) {
        $regexSearch[]['text'] = new MongoRegex("/" . $value . "/");
    }

    //words included
    foreach ($cardInclu as $value) {
        $regexInclu[]['text'] = new MongoRegex("/" . $value . "/");
    }

    //words excluded
    foreach ($cardExlu as $value) {
        $regexExclu[]['text'] = new MongoRegex("/" . $value . "/");
    }

    $arr['$and'] = $regexInclu;
    $arr['$ne'] = $regexExclu;
    array_push($regexSearch, $arr);

    $i = $mongoCollection->count(array('$or' => $regexSearch));
```

or

```
    $i = $mongoCollection->count(array('$or' => $regexSearch, 
         '$and' => $regexInclu, '$ne' => $regexExclu));
```

Thanks!